# MariaDB views: I want to replace repeated multi-table joins in my queries with a view - are there any issues to watch out for?

Tags: mariadb

Rather than

```
SELECT a.pk, b.pk, c.pk, d.name

FROM a
JOIN b on b.pk = a.fk
JOIN c on c.pk = b.fk
JOIN d on d.pk = c.fk
```

I can do

```
SELECT a_pk, b_pk, c_pk, d_name

FROM view_a_b_c_d
```

I have a lot of this sort of thing through my code.

I've done a performance test, and the differences seem to be negligible, and I feel it would greatly tidy my codebase up and remove a lot of repetition.

But before I commit to that (as it'd be a big change with a lot of work and testing), I want to check that this IS a good thing to do.  I didn't study computer science and have no formal DBA training.  I'm also a sole dev working on my own closed-source product.  So I don't get much input from the outside world, unless I strike out and ask for it.

Thank you - any opinions/experience appreciated.

Comment: In _some_ situations there could be a performance degradation.  Otherwise, Views should like a good idea for you.  If any of those are 1:1 relationships, then rethink that.  If you are using an EAV schema, _that_ is problematic (with or without Views).

Comment: Newer versions of mysql, mariadb seems to handle views much better than what used to be the case. Older versions had problems pushing predicates through the view to the Base tables. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm on the latest stable release 

Comment: No @Rick James, I think my schema is ok.  Example would be events joined to organisers, venues and event series.

Comment: @Codemonkey -- Latest stable release of _which_ product?  Lennart is pointing out a significant difference in how `JOINs` are optimized between MySQL (even the latest version) and recent versions of MariaDB.  Or maybe you should remove the `mysql` tag to avoid this confusion.

Comment: MariaDB 10.5.8 